# LMM predicted mean RTs for specific subject and word (based on my model's contrast coding)in R?

Tags: r, lme4

## Instruction: calculate the model's predicted mean reaction time for trials in which the previous judgment was on a word(word=1,non-word=-1) and the subject(native speaker=1,other=-1) is a native speaker of English. As opposed to applying coef() to the model, you have to use the method shown below (#summary(your_model)$coefficients) to extract the estimated values in table form. The values themselves can then be accessed using [,] syntax. Verify that the calculated mean from the model matches the value calculated from the data.

### My contrast coding

```
lexdec$PrevCont<-ifelse(lexdec$PrevType%in%c("word"),1,-1)
lexdec$NativeCont<-ifelse(lexdec$NativeLanguage%in%c("English"),1,-1)
```

### My fitted model

M1<- lmer(RT ~ PrevCont * NativeCont  + (1 + PrevCont * NativeCont|Subject) + (1 +PrevCont * NativeCont|Word), data=lexdec)

```
##Please anyone know how i can do this?
```

Comment: Hey Chris, please don't use abbreviations. I have no idea what LMM or RT means, and I'm pretty sure many others who want to help won't either. And it's not clear what you want help with. What is "this" in "...how to do this?"  Are you asking someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: Hi Edwards, this is my first post actually, i meant linear mixed models and reaction times. And no, I'm not asking anyone to do my assignment for me. what i'm asking for is an explanation on how to go about it. I have done a bunch of stuff on the data up to that point, but that part is confusing to me. i only added those details for clarity sake as suggested by the site. All i need is for someone to point me to the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The original question gave some hints already.

```
summary(M1)$coefficients
```

gives the coefficients for the summary of the fixed effects, which is a matrix. So you can then extract the estimates from the *first* column using [,] as hinted. I'm sure you can do that. :)

As for the means of the RT variable for the various levels of the two variables PrevCont and NativeCont, you can use the tapply function for that:

```
with(lexdec, 
  tapply(RT, list(PrevCont, NativeCont), FUN=mean)
)
```

The value in the lower right hand corner is the mean reaction time for subjects who were native (NativeCont=1) and the previous judgment was on a word (PrevCont=1). I think.

This value (6.2804) is very close the calculated mean from the model (6.2812).

Comment: Thanks a lot Edward, you nailed it. It worked perfectly.